# What are the possible combinations from 111 to 999 if we remove the combinations that contain zero?

Tags: solution-verification

I tried finding it like this

111 to 119 is 9
so 111 to 199 is 89
and 211 to 299 is 89 and so on.
Then i multiplied 89 with 9 and got **801**.

Is this correct?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Well, not exactly. Your 89 contains numbers like 120, 130, 150 and so on.
The correct answer would be 9^3=729 because you can put any 9 numbers on the first place, any 9 numbers on the second and any 9 numbers pn the third place.